# PayPal API (оплата совершается, но с карты ничего не списывается)

Tags: php, paypal

Использую метод [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), получаю успешно token, после, передаю его по ссылке, чтобы пользователь мог произвести оплату:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=<? echo $token[1]; ?>
```

Скрипт создания token'a:

```
$paypal_create_token = post('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp', 
 array(
  'params' => array(
   'USER' => $paypal_config['user'],
   'PWD' => $paypal_config['password'],
   'SIGNATURE' => $paypal_config['sign'],
   'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
   'VERSION' => $paypal_config['version'],
   'REQCONFIRMSHIPPING' => 0,
   'NOSHIPPING' => 1,
   'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
   'LANDINGPAGE' => 'Billing',
   'LOGOIMG' => $protocol.'://'.$host.'/images/logo197x40.png?'.$time,
   'HDRIMG' => $protocol.'://'.$host.'/images/logo.png?'.$time,
   'BRANDNAME' => mb_strtoupper($host),
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $amount,
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => $amount,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => $amount,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => $description,
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM' => $order_id,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0' => $order_id,
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'SALE',
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'RUB',
   'EMAIL' => $orders_info['email'],
   'RETURNURL' => $paypal_config['success_url'].'?order_id='.$order_id.'&order_hash='.$order_hash,
   'CANCELURL' => $paypal_config['fail_url'].'?order_id='.$order_id.'&order_hash='.$order_hash,
  )
 )
);

$paypal_create_token_content = $paypal_create_token['content'];

preg_match('/TOKEN\=(.*?)\&/', $paypal_create_token_content, $token); // получаем token
```

В итоге всё как нужно, появляется страница оплаты счёта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И когда я нажимаю на **Продолжить**, то всё проходит успешно, но средства с карты не списываются, будто установлен тестовый режим, хотя не используется ссылка sandbox. Ради интереса решил подключить свой аккаунт PayPal на мои API данные к одному платёжному сервису, там после оплаты, с карты средства списались.

И ещё, иногда банк запрашивает смс-код, чтобы подтвердить платёж, но всё равно ничего не списывается. Странности.

В чём проблема? Не использую ссылку sandbox, но всё равно такая вот беда. Подозреваю, что передал в параметры что-то не то.

Comment: А может, было бы лучше, спросить сначала в саппорте PayPal-а? Они бы смогли проверить как проходит платёж, и если он идёт как тестовый, подсказали бы что к чему. Вдруг у вас проблема не в коде, а в настройках палки? :)

Comment: @intro94, если была бы проблема в настройке палки, тогда бы и оплата у стороннего платёжного сервиса с моими данными не сработала.

`Ради интереса решил подключить свой аккаунт PayPal к одному платежному сервису, там после оплаты, с карты средства списались.`

Comment: А разве приём платежей не отдельно от "личного кошелька" настраивается? Я с палкой не разбирался, так как её поддержка в моей стране нулевая, но обычно приём платежей во всех системах настраивается отдельно (знаю на примере WM, робокасса, w1, киви и многих других).

Comment: @intro94, сервис digiseller позволяет указать свои данные PayPal и принимать оплату через свой аккаунт PayPal.

Comment: Тогда я вовсе потерялся. Платёжные агрегаторы тем и хороши, что пользователю достаточно настроить API самих агрегаторов, а про свои личные аккаунты в платёжных системах можно забыть - у агрегатора свои шлюзы должны быть, и огромное кол-во ПС на борту. В общем я вам тогда не помощник в вашей ситуации, прошу прощения. :(

Comment: @intro94, возможно, Вы не поняли суть. Я хочу сделать оплату без всяких сервисов, сам, напрямую через PayPal, но у меня почему-то не списываются средства с карты. А если я беру сервис digiseller и прописываю там свои данные API, то списываются. Может я неправильно какие-то параметры передаю просто.

Comment: Действительно, я не понял суть. Но сейчас тем более не подскажу. Напрямую с палкой я никогда не работал. В общем, прошу прощения за бесполезное обсуждение. P.S.: но если здесь никто не ответит, всё же рекомендовал бы обратиться в саппорт палки. Он там не просто так существует. Такие проблемы наверняка им знакомы. :)

Comment: @intro94, после того как Вы сказали написать им, я написал :) Вот только неизвестно сколько ждать ответа :/

Comment: Если вы решите проблему сами (или с помощью саппорта) было бы неплохо написать сюда. Думаю, если кто-то столкнётся с такой проблемой после вас, сможет найти ответ здесь (ну и мне будет полезно знать на будущее xD). :) P.S.: обычно саппорт отвечает в течении суток.

Comment: @intro94, ага, напишу. Я нагуглил много таких тем, но ответов нигде не было. Может стану первым :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось очень просто, я не подтверждал транзакцию после редиректа на страницу успешной оплаты, на которую GET запросом передавались параметры `token` и `PayerID`.

Подтверждать транзакцию нужно таким образом:

```
post('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp', 
 array(
  'params' => array(
   'USER' => $paypal_config['user'],
   'PWD' => $paypal_config['password'],
   'SIGNATURE' => $paypal_config['sign'],
   'METHOD' => 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment',
   'VERSION' => $paypal_config['version'],
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $amount,
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => $amount,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => $amount,
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM' => $order_id,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0' => $order_id,
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'SALE',
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'RUB',
   'token' => ((isset($_GET['token'])) ? $_GET['token'] : ''),
   'payerid' => ((isset($_GET['PayerID'])) ? $_GET['PayerID'] : '')
  )
 )
);
```

За помощь огромное спасибо участнику английского stackoverflow — https://stackoverflow.com/a/37434689/5184005